# multiple format specifiers in one expression

Tags: python

Is there a way to use multiple format specifiers in one expression?

```
In [1]: '{:,}'.format(12345)
Out[1]: '12,345'

In [2]: '{:<10}'.format(12345)
Out[2]: '12345     '

# Can i do something like?
In [3]: '{:<somemagic here>}'.format(12345)
Out[3]: '12,345    '
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [22]: '{:<10,}'.format(12345)
Out[22]: '12,345    '
```